# How to handle this linear optimization problem with missing values?

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-regression, linear-programming

Let's consider this example code:

```
rng('default')

% creating fake data
data = randi([-1000 +1000],30,500);
yt = randi([-1000 1000],30,1);

% creating fake missing values
row = randi([1 15],1,500);
col = rand(1,500) < .5;

% imputing missing fake values
for i = 1:500
    if col(i) == 1
        data(1:row(i),i) = nan;
    end
end

%% here starts my problem
wgts = ones(1,500); % optimal weights needs to be binary (only zero or one)

% this would be easy with matrix formulas but I have missing values at the
% beginning of the series
for j = 1:30
    xt(j,:) = sum(data(j,:) .* wgts,2,'omitnan');
end


X = [xt(3:end) xt(2:end-1) xt(1:end-2)];
y = yt(3:end);

% from here I basically need to:
% maximize the Adjusted R squared of the regression fitlm(X,y)
% by changing wgts
% subject to wgts = 1 or wgts = 0
% and optionally to impose sum(wgts,'all') = some number;

% basically I need to select the data cols with the highest explanatory
% power, omitting missing data
```

This is relatively easy to implement with Excel solver, but but it can handle only 200 decision variables and it takes a lot of time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you want some version of `intlinprog`

Comment: The omitting missing data part is rather easy, since you just have to set the `NaN` values to `0` and they won't interfere in any way. The rest I'm not sure I get it. You are looking to select a subset of columns for which a linear fit with `fitlm` is going to have the maximum R squared? If so then the answer is always going to be the whole set of columns.

Comment: @BillBokeey of course the R squared increases as result of an increase of the number of independent variables. It's not the R squared i want to maximize, but the Adjusted R squared that takes it into account.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually the solution you look for? The classical way to extract a minimal subset of variables to explain an output is to run something like `pca`

Comment: how do you implement pca when the number of regressors is much more greater than the number of observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lasso](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html#d123e566915) seems to give interesting results:

```
% creating fake data (but having an actual relationship between `yt` and the predictors)
rng('default')
data = randi([-1000 +1000],30,500);
alphas = rand(1,500);
yt = sum(alphas.*data,2) + 10*randn(30,1);
plot(yt)
```

[image]

```
% Use lasso algorithm with no constant coefficients
% keep the column of coefficients that minimizes MSE.
% By design, lasso minimizes the amount of non zero coefficients

[B,FitInfo] = lasso(data,yt,'Intercept',false);
idxLambda1SE = find(FitInfo.MSE == min(FitInfo.MSE));
coef = B(:,idxLambda1SE);
y_verif = data*coef;
hold on;plot(y_verif)
```

[image]

`sum(coef~=0)`

> ans =
>
> ```
> 29
> ```

Output has been explained by 29 columns only, whereas all the values in `alpha` were non zero

Comment: Thank you for your response. The lasso gives an interesting output but I have two independent variable (which should be just a linear combination of the relevant independent variables) lags in my regression and it would be a problem

Comment: With 500 independent variables two lag gives a 28 x 1500 covariates matrix and furthermore the lasso may shrink some independent variable but not one of its lags